# How to extract raster attributes by lat/long location?

Tags: raster, r

How can you extract an attribute value from a raster from a point (lat/long)?

Example data: Raster with attribute table - value of interest is temperature

I have a list of points with lat/long values, which I want to extract the temperature values for. The raster contains multiple attribute values, temp is not the "pixel" value

Comment: What software or language are you using? Also, have you searched this question? It's a very common/basic one and it's likely it's already been answered for you.

Comment: Well I am trying to do this in R using the raster library. I've also tried georasters and rasterio. I can get the values, but there are other attributes in the raster I want to return. That is the issue. Yes I have searched.

Comment: BTW - The values I want to capture are in the associated VAT.dbf table. Source file is a GeoTiff created in ArcGIS. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that your rasters are also in a geographic projection, all you have to do is pass a matrix of lat,long coordinates to the raster extract function. This will a vector of values corresponding to each row in the matrix. Or, in the case of a raster stack, a data.frame where columns represent each rasters values, still organized by row.

Answer (score 4):

As it is you do not include a reproducible example. But assuming you're using R and you have a single layer raster:

```
location = data.frame(x = -68.8901643,
                      y = 44.9142272)
coordinates(location) <- ~x+y
mypoints = SpatialPoints(location,proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

myproj = CRS(myraster)
points.proj = spTransform(mypoints, myproj)
myvalues = extract(raster, points.proj)
```

If you have more than one lat/long pair you can extract everything at once by using a data.frame with more rows, e.g.:

```
location = data.frame(x = c(-68.8901643,-70,-72,-74),
                      y = c(44.9142272,45,47,49))
```

Comment: I am new to R so I don't don't know whether to use extract or some other command for selecting by lat/long values. Your example doesn't provide lat long parameters. I just want to return an attribute value for a given lat/long location in a raster. Thanks.

Comment: I tried val = cellFromXY(data_tif, c(-68.8901643,44.9142272)) but it doesn't return the value from the VAT.

Comment: @Jim ok see the updated answer